# Can i access my own FB page using just my email and passwd?

Tags: facebook, web-applications, desktop-application

I am thinking of building an app(web or desktop) with which i can access my facebook account using only my email and password.

Is it possible?

What are the best ways ? Any tutorials or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

yes, its possible.

Check the facebook API at http://developers.facebook.com/

Comment: NitinJS  , I already know about the docs. I can't see any info about what I am asking. I you are aware of any such article , send me the specific link

Comment: Using the facebook api means using Outh , meaning making an app which accesses fb taking my permissions . My app would just take my username and password , and do what I ask it to do, no permissions to ask. Such as a bot. Please read my question. I just wanna interact with the app by giving it my id and password, nothing else.

Comment: its not possible.. the user must allow/deny access to his profile

Answer (score 0):

You would have to rely on scraping Facebook.  There are a few tutorials out there but its the same as scraping any other site: watching the urls and post values that get sent back and forth, storing the session login cookie, and then parsing the returned html. However, this is against their TOS and could cause your IP or account to be banned, on top of the measures they have in place to prevent against scraping such as randomly introducing captchas if they detect bots and making sure the IP address geolocation is similar to locations the user normally access Facebook from (making it tough to do a server solution to manage users accounts with their email/password.